# Error while trying to use webdriver from selenium

Tags: python

I am new to coding and require selenium for web-scraping.
I use Jupyter from the Anaconda navigator. I have conda installed selenium. I have downloaded geckodriver. However, I am running into an error with the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\Users\Public\geckodriver.exe")
```

> Error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode
>   bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

So I try with doubles backstrokes

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\Users\\Public\\geckodriver.exe")
```

> NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
>   'C:\Users\Public\geckodriver.exe'

I am not sure what to do from here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `geckodriver.exe` in the same folder as your `.py` file and run your code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```